# Dynamic Linq core

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, dynamic-linq

Hi I am using a Jqwidgets Grid to display my data. It has a build in possibility to use filters but if you filter your records on the server side you have to build your own query. As I am working with Linq I thought to use the Dynamic Linq Library for Asp net core. Problem is there are not many examples or explanations how to do this. But I am busy for days now and not getting very far.The way I am setup; I have a normal Linq query:

```
 var Mut = from M in _DB.Mutations
                  join S in _DB.Shifts on M.ShiftId equals S.ShiftId
                  join U in _DB.RoosterUsers on M.UserId equals U.RoosterUserId
                  join D in deps on M.UserId equals D.UserId
                  join DD in _DB.Departements on D.DepartementID equals DD.DepartementId
                  select new MutationModel
                  {
                      MutId=M.MutationId,
                      Naam=U.FirstName + " " + U.LastName,
                      UserId=M.UserId,
                      Departement= DD.DepartementName,
                      MutationType = S.publicName,
                      MutationGroup = S.ShiftType.ToString(),
                      DateTot =M.DateTill,
                      TijdVan=M.DateStartOn,
                      TijdTot=M.DateTill,
                      Status=CreateStatus(M.Tentative, M.ApprovedOn, M.Processed, M.CancelRefId, M.Deleted)
                  };
```

This query is running OK and gives me all the data I need for the Grid.

Then for the filter I would like to add a dynamic Linq Query using the System.Linq.Dynamic.Core library
But this is as far as I get things working until now:

```
var outQuery = Mut.Where("Status = @0 and UserId = @1", "Nieuw", "KLM22940").Select("Status");
```

My questions now :
1. In the where clause If I make the fieldname variable I get an error. how to do this?? 
2. In the Select Clause, how to add multiple Columns? (actually I just like to output all columns.)

3. Best would be to see an example. has somebody used Dynamic Linq to build a dynamic linq query for the JQWidgets Grid?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How are you attempting to make the fieldname variable? Show what you are trying. Anonymous objects are created with `"new(field1, field2 as name2, field3)"`. See [here](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions).

Comment: I did var outQuery = Mut.Where("@0 = @1","Status", "Nieuw") but this gives an error.

Comment: You need to do `var f = "Status"; outQuery = Mut.Where($"{f} = @1", "Nieuw")` - you can't use parameters for fieldnames.

Comment: This ($"{f} = @0", "Nieuw") seems to work. But I do not understand what you are doing here. could you please explain what the $ is meaning here?

Comment: Yes this is working: var f = "Status";
            var outQuery = Mut.Where($"{f} = @0", "Nieuw").Select("new(MutId, Naam, UserId, Status)"); I will continue with this tomorrow. thank you Ian for your help.

Comment: `$"{variable}"` is string interpolation, a C# feature to use `String.Format` in an easier way: it is equivalent to `String.Format("{0}", variable)`. You can have multiple variables inserted into the string.

Answer (score 0):

In what way you are trying to use fieldname variable in where clause ?

If you want to output all columns you can use ToList()
like

```
var outQuery = Mut.Where("Status = @0 and UserId = @1", "Nieuw", "KLM22940").ToList();
```

If you want to get some specific columns you can use Select clause like this

```
var outQuery = Mut.Where("Status = @0 and UserId = @1", "Nieuw", "KLM22940").Select("new(Status,UserId )");
```

This Select clause creates data class which contains Status and UserId properties and returns a sequence of instances of that data class.